# Finding the covariance of a stock portfolio

Tags: portfolio-theory, stock-market, statistics

So my question goes like this, I have the returns of 3 different stocks AAPL, NKE and BBRY
I make 4 portfolios out of them as follows:

[image: my stock portfolios]

and the question asks me to compute the correlation coefficient and covariance for each portfolio...

Now this seems a bit odd to me, since it already asked me to compute the covariance and correlation of each stock pair in an earlier question. Also, how would I go about doing it for the portfolio with 3 stocks?

Comment: Hint: The difference is the 1) portfolios are weighted unevenly between stocks, and 2) you can't just sum the variances to get the whole. You need to add covariances also..

Comment: So am I suppose to find the weighted variance of the portfolio and use that as the covariance?  i.e. 
$$
Cov[Portfolio] = \sum_{i=0}^n \sigma_i^2w_i^2 + \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k\ne i} w_iw_k\sigma_{i,k}\sigma_i\sigma_k
$$
So like for the 3 stock portfolio I will be using
$$
Cov[Portfolio] = \sum_{i=0}^3 \sigma_n^2w_n^2 + 2w_1w_2\sigma_{1,2}\sigma_1\sigma_2+ 2w_1w_3\sigma_{1,3}\sigma_1\sigma_3+ 2w_2w_3\sigma_{3,2}\sigma_3\sigma_2
$$

Comment: Looks great to me!

Comment: Now how would I get the correlation?

Comment: The correlation can be found if you know the covariance.


http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/correlation-matrix-from-covariance-matrix